# PowerShell Script to Find and Replace for all Files

Tags: powershell

I have many `.cmd` and `.ps1` files in `C:\Foo` folder and subfolders, I need to replace the word "*vanilla*" with the word "*chocolate*" **case insensitive** in all files within that folder and subfolders.

This is how I do it:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Foo *.cmd *.ps1 -recurse |
    Foreach-Object {
        $c = ($_ | Get-Content) 
        $c = $c -replace 'vanilla','chocolate'
        [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
    }
```

I use `[IO.File]::WriteAllText` only because `Set-Content` adds new line at the end (I don't get why though).

The issue is that it opens and writes to all files, even files that don't contain the word '*vanilla*', and therefore modifies time stamp of all files. How do I improve the script so it `WriteAllText` only to files that has been changed by `replace` operation i.e. files that contain the word '*vanilla*'?

Comment: Code works fine for me ,i had to remove one of the wild card parameters in the get-childitem (checked in v4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an `if` statement to check if 'vanilla' exists in the file:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Foo *.cmd *.ps1 -recurse |
    Foreach-Object {
        $c = ($_ | Get-Content) 
        if(($c -join "").contains("vanilla")){
            $c = $c -replace 'vanilla','chocolate'
            [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
        }
    }
```